# Apache vhost always show me the same content on different subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have two subdomains on my VPS, i have registered the two subdomains in my DNS pointing to the same IP address.

the version installed is Server version: Apache/2.4.7 for Ubuntu 12.04.

I've enabled the sites with the `a2ensite` command and i have enable the module `vhost_alias`. restart and reloaded many times

## `stable.example.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
    ServerName stable.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/stable/web

    <Directory /var/www/stable/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## `beta.example.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName beta.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta/web

    <Directory /var/www/beta/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my trouble is pointing my browser to any url always i get the same content and to add more confusion when i execute `service apache2 reload` in the two subdomains i get the content from `beta.example.com` and when execute `service apache2 restart` in the two subdomains i get the content of `stable.example.com`.

I have spent about 5 hours trying to fix this

### update

event i try with the `VirtualDocumentRoot`

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%1/web"
    ServerName stable.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "/var/www/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

with the same behavior explained before this update

### update 2

I dont have virtualhost overlap, every vhost has unique name and unique DocumentoRoot, even i have the `<VirtualHost _defaut_:80>` defined.

i check with `apachectl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:220)
         port 80 namevhost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:220)
         port 80 namevhost beta.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/beta.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost stable.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/stable.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: maybe you have virtualhost overlap, and think you missing the directive NameVirtualHost *:80 read this http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TroubleshootingVhosts and you are missing the default virtual host http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: the directorive `NameVirtualHost` is deprecated `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release`

Comment: Did you try removing the default server configuration in httpd.conf?

Comment: @edvinas.me yes i removed it

Comment: can you post apache2.conf as the problem is due to something in that config file.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem running multiple virtual hosts locally - using :

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

Instead of:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

In the http-vhosts.conf file fixed it for me.

Comment: You could do without NameVirtualHost as well, if you use <VirtualHost *:80>

Answer (score -2):

### Update

This is likely caused by apache2.conf

```
default server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:220)
```

You should post your apache2.conf

### httpd.conf (or apache.conf or apache2.conf depending on distribution)

Make sure you have these:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Make sure there is no other NameVirtualHost directive in main config.

### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
    ServerName stable.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/stable/web
    UseCanonicalName on
    <Directory /var/www/stable/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName beta.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta/web
    UseCanonicalName on
    <Directory /var/www/beta/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure that you default httpd.conf configuration does not include any defined servers, as vhosts might be overlapping with that.

Comment: i append the `UseCaninicalName on` without success

Comment: I am afraid appending will not fix this as it is clear the problem is caused by some other part of your config. I would guess it is `port 80 namevhost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:220)` So please use default apache2.conf with only php setup and my vhost configs.